# What are the foursquare API rules about returning the "facebook" field for venues?

Tags: api, foursquare

This page -- https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue -- specifies the fields returned by a venue query, and lists whether or not they are always returned or only sometimes returned.

This venue has a facebook URL specified:

https://foursquare.com/v/specialty-produce/4ab5b07df964a520d57520e3

But when I get the venue data from a venue search, it does not include that field (see below) and it is not listed in the document for the Venue endpoint located at

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue

I therefore can't tell if it should be expected in the contact object (which is where the twitter page is) or up one level (which is where the venue URL is located) and whether or not it is in either the compact or complete object some/none/all of the time.

Note that I *am* sometimes seeing a "facebook" field, such as this venue:

https://foursquare.com/v/somewhere-loud/5179ef7fe4b076127bf04922

which returns the following "contact" dictionary

```
"contact":{"twitter":"somewhereloud","facebook":"461351130570902"},
```

Here's an example of a response with no facebook field, even though the venue has one shown on their page on foursquare.

```
{"venues":[{"id":"4ab5b07df964a520d57520e3","name":"Specialty Produce",
"contact":{"phone":"6192953172","formattedPhone":"(619) 295-3172","twitter":"specialtyprod"},
"location":{"address":"1929 Hancock St, #150","crossStreet":"Noell Street",
```

How do I determine when and where to find this field for any particular venue?

Comment: Maybe you should tell foursquare to update the docs instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: austin - foursquare specifically uses stackoverflow for their support "forum".  Clicking on "support" takes you here.  I admit I should have phrased it as a question to stay in line with SO's format.

Comment: @DaveNewton-- thanks for the edits!  You rock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook URLs aren't always returned in the `contact` object in a venues response; only the fields currently documented are guaranteed to be returned.

On Foursquare's own venue pages, if the venue has a page associated with it, the Facebook URL may be pulled from the `user` object within the `page` object. For the example you gave, you can see that the Facebook ID (which translates to the URL) comes from `response.venue.page.user.contact.facebook`: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/4ab5b07df964a520d57520e3

Comment: octopi, if that is true then why am I sometimes getting a "facebook" value filled in?  I will edit the question to include an example

Comment: There's one of two scenarios: (1) the venue has a facebook ID associated with it or (2) the chain that the venue belongs to has a facebook ID associated with it. In the case of (2), you'll find the facebook ID in the page user object associated with the venue. We display them identically on the rendered venue page, but the API retains the two different places where the ID can come from.

Comment: And what questions, exactly, on SO do not fall into the "update your docs" category?  That's a specious, overbroad response AND the precise cause has absolutely nothing to do with my statement about the poor system currently in place.  If anything, it serves to highlight my point.